# Css sticky menu height re sizing incorrectly

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

Why when I do scroll, height of the navigation is resizing and becoming bigger than it should be. How can I fix this problem?

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/9Leq24dq/

```js
$(function() {
  var navOffset = $('nav').offset().top;
  $("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
  $(".nav-placeholder").height($("nav").outerHeight());

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
      $("nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      $("nav").removeClass("fixed");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#menu {
  text-align: center;
}
header {
  width: 950px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #1B78EA;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
}
header h1 {
  line-height: 120px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav {
  background-color: #7B7B7B;
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-palceholder {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 49px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: #999999;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 2px #646464;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Id optio blanditiis, beatae voluptatem enim consequuntur, in inventore necessitatibus laborum, amet ab? Consequuntur fugiat dolorem dolore, amet dolores repudiandae, voluptates dicta!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is adding a margin to the ul when it is fixed. You could add this rule to remove that margin and keep the nav the same height:

```
.fixed ul{
  margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify .nav height

```
 nav  {
    background-color: #7B7B7B;
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: ; /* for ex. 75px */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better to reset the default `padding` and `margin` for the `ul`:

```
.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5fhmro0/)**

Comment: By the way there is an extra `</div>` should be removed from the markup.